# The definite article with the intangible nouns

Tags: articles

Why it is right to use "the rain" and "the lottery" in the following sentences?

> If you stand in the rain, you get wet.
>
> If I won the lottery, I would travel a lot.

Can I use "a" instead of first or second "the"?

(It becomes hard, when a noun means an abstract object.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The* lottery refers to a particular one (the main lottery in your country, or one you have just been talking about). *A* lottery would mean just any one.

As for rain, it's just usual in English to use *the* before weather phenomena in some contexts. *He got lost in the snow. The fence blew down in the wind.* It's less usual to use *a*, but we can do so when describing a particular quality of the weather. *A light rain began to fall.*

Comment: Why then "Tears in rain" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears_in_rain_monologue is written without any article? Why not "The tears in the rain" or "Tears in the rain"?

Comment: Note that I deliberately said _in some contexts_. That phrase appears to refer to tears in general and rain in general, not the rain on a particular day.